# Thailand: Getting a Re-entry Permit on a Land Border

Tags: visa, thailand

I know it is also possible to get a re-entry permit in both int. airports.

Is it possible also on land-borders, specifically, Laos via Nong-Khai?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible to get a re-entry permit at an immigration office (e.g. the government centre at Chaengwattana in Bangkok), but from memory I don't think it's possible at the borders.

Please be aware that a re-entry permit does not affect the date by which you must leave Thailand - it merely allows you to exit and re-enter as if it was your previous entry. So if you get a 90-day stamp when entering Thailand, then get a re-entry permit and go out then come back, your previous 90-day stamp is still valid, and you must exit within 90 days of your original entry.

Comment: It is possible at borders - at least Nong Khai. See [my new answer](http://expatriates.stackexchange.com/a/8673/9854)

Answer (score 4):

Yes, it is possible.

Evidence:

1. It is, as of 1 July 2016, explicty stated on the [Nong Khai Immigration](http://nongkhai.immigration.go.th/index.php) web site that this is possible (see screenshot below)
2. I telephoned Nong Khai immigration to check, to make absolutely sure, and they said that it is. They also said that the re-entry desk is open until 10pm, I think on weekdays. But you would want to check this.
3. I got a re-entry permit from Thai border control at the friendship bridge myself in June 2016. I got the permit during regular working hours, i.e. before 16:30.

[image: Nong Khai Immigration web site]

Answer (score 1):

No, you cannot do this on land.

In the international airport, they have a special re-entry desk. However, for land border, you should have a origin country. In the case of Laos, you should come from Laos. This means, when you leave Thailand, you should enter Laos and leave Laos to be eligible to enter Thailand again.

Comment: so leaving Thailand on a land border, I must posses a reentry already. Understood. But then, if I want to continue to Vietnam for example and then fly back to Thailand, this cannot be done? What are the reasons for that?

Comment: @user1248826 For any entry, you should come from another country. You can go to Laos, Vietnam, Malaysia for just one minute, but when you enter Thailand you have actually left the origin country. This is the general rule. The airport re-entry point is an exceptional service, but it is not valid in any other border.

Comment: I think you mis-understand what a re-entry permit actually is. It's not something to re-set a multiple-entry visa, it's something that allows you to enter Thailand on the same visa you left. If you have a non-immigrant visa and leave without a re-entry permit, your visa will effectively be cancelled. This happened to a friend of mine. Anyway, back to the OP's question: the answer is definitely *yes*.